# paper-radio-group-changed not firing when a radio button is selected by script

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I have a `paper-radio-group` that listens to event `paper-radio-group-changed`. This event fires perfectly when someone manually click the radio button, but it does not fire when it is assigned by script. Here is how I assign it by script

```
<paper-radio-group id="prg">
    <paper-radio-button name="a">A</paper-radio-button>
    <paper-radio-button name="b">B</paper-radio-button>
    <paper-radio-button name="c">C</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>

...
<script>
    $("#prg").selected = "a";
    $(document).on('paper-radio-group-changed', '#prg', {}, function (e) {
      //Whatever here is not executed
    });
</script>
```

More observations:

The radio button `"a"` is actually get selected. But the event is never fired. Why? Did I choose the wrong event listener or need additional event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paper-radio-group-changed` is fired when a selection change happens through the method `select(itemName)`:

```
// paper-radio-group-changed

let prg = document.querySelector('#prg');

prg.select('b');

prg.addEventListener('paper-radio-group-changed', e => {
    alert('paper-radio-group-changed');
});
// jQuery on() works as well
```

Listening to changes in the `selected` attribute is possible by using `Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior`'s `selected-changed` event:

```
// selected-changed

prg.selected = 'b';

prg.addEventListener('selected-changed', e => {
    alert('selected-changed');
});
```

Find more information on paper-radio-group and its events [here](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-radio-group/elements/paper-radio-group).

### Two notes on jQuery + Polymer

Elements in the Shadow DOM are not so easy to select with jQuery [Using jQuery with shadow dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155218/using-jquery-with-shadow-dom).

Setting custom attributes with jQuery don't always behave how Polymer expects:

```
$('#prg').attr({foo: 'bar'}); // These syntaxes should work
$('#prg').attr('foo': 'bar');
// However for the attribute 'selected', being a valid HTML 
// attribute which accepts a true/false (set/undefined) value pair,
// the value is ingored by jQuery resulting in selected="selected"
$('#prg').attr('selected', 'b');
```

so selecting with `document.querySelector()` is probably safer in this case.

Note that if you place `<paper-radio-group id="prg">` inside of another polymer element (i.e. `<my-app></my-app>`) you can access it using `this.$`:

```
class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return  'my-app' }
  ready() {
    super.ready();
    this.$.prg.selected = 'b';
  }
}
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#node-finding

Comment: Perfect explanation about matching the event and method. Thank you. And also thank you for reminding me about the jQuery issue. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You need to think in Polymer.

html

```
<paper-radio-group selectedAttribute="name" selected="{{selected}}">
```

js

```
this.selected = "a";

/*
 * observer on the property, selected
 */
```

Comment: This might work but unfortunately I have nowhere to test it because the object is dynamically generated so it is hard to put escape in my JS string (i.e. `$.parseHTML("{{selected}}")` will give me plain text `{{selected}}`). I went with the accepted answer but still thank you.

Comment: I endorse Frank R. We must think in Polymer.