# Fetch page with jQuery and extract all links with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to fetch a page with jQuery and then extract values from the response, specifically I want to access all `href` attributes of `a` tags with a specific `class`.

The page is on the same domain, so there are no cross origin problems. The specific page returns a HTML page, but it would be great if it would work regardless of the content type.

What I have so far:

```
// the page to fetch (index2.html). 
<html>
<a href="/example" class="getthis">click</a>
<a href="/example2" class="getthis">click2</a>
</html>
```

On this page, this JS code works fine:

```
$('.getthis').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

What I now tried is this:

```
$.get('/index2.html', function(data){
    $(data).find('.getthis').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
    })
});
```

Fetching the page works fine, but extracting the data does not work. I tried a lot of variations on this idea, but none seem to work.

How can I fetch a HTML page with jQuery and then work on the DOM of the response, eg to extract all elements with a specific class?

I'm using jQuery 3.3.1, but it would be great if a solution would work on all versions.

Comment: what is `console.log(data)`

Comment: @brk `$.get('/index2.html', function(data){console.log(data)})` prints out the HTML source of the index2.html page.

Comment: are you appending this `data` anywhere in the dom?

Comment: @brk no, the code I posted is all I have. Is appending the data required? I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require that.

Answer (score 2):

Parse your data from ajax to DOM node via **$.parseHTML()**.
And find element via **.filter()**

```
$.get('/index2.html', function(data){
    data = $.parseHTML(data);
    $(data).filter('.getthis').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
    })
});
```

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: actually, this only works if the `a` tag is at the top level. If it is eg inside a div, `filter` doesn't seem to work anymore. I'm not that familiar with jQuery; is there a way to use `filter` to access all elements of a class, no matter where they are in the DOM?

Comment: try to change .filter() to .find()

Comment: filter() can catch elements satisfied with your condition from current set of element. find() can catch descendants(which have ancestor element).
If your anchor tag is top level, use filter(). Or not, use find()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378757/difference-between-find-and-filter-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think,You can parse data like that

Create an invisible `div`

```
<div id="index2Data" style="display:none"></div>
```

and set data into this

```
$.get('/index2.html', function(data){
    var container = document.querySelector('#index2Data');
    var root = container.createShadowRoot();
    $(root).html(data);
    $(root).find('.getthis').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks! That works, though I would prefer it if I didn't need the workaround with an invisible div, but could work on the data directly. This seems like a somewhat common use-case, but maybe it's just not possible?

Comment: I think it would be better to insert the loaded content in shadow DOM than real DOM, even if it's hidden. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155218/using-jquery-with-shadow-dom?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work directly with the "data" and typeof data === "string" as in your example this might work for you:

```js
var links;

$.ajax('index2.html').done(function (data) {
    // note that data is just a string
    // get all a tags with specific class
    links = data.match(/<a.*class=['|"]getthis['|"].*>/gi);

    // iterate over links and ...
    links.forEach(function (item, index) {

        // remove everything in front of the href attr value ...
        var start = item.indexOf('href=') + 6;
        links[index] = item.substring(start);

        // then remove everything after the href attr value
        var end = links[index].indexOf('"') > - 1
        ? links[index].indexOf('"') 
        : links[index].indexOf('\'');

        links[index] = links[index].substring(0, end);
    });
});

console.log(links);
```